# ASRock C2550D4I, fine before update and reboot, afterwards IPMI status is fine but Remote Console and VGA is blank

Tags: centos, ipmi

I've got a machine with ASRock C2550D4I. It's running CentOS6. Yesterday, I've executed yum update and rebooted the machine. Afterwards, I was not able to login via ssh to CentOS (only to IPMI). I've checked the IPMI interface via http. Everything seems fine, nevertheless the remote console is not working - it used to work before. Then, I've plugged in a VGA display but it's blank as well.

Should I assume the board is dead or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you try reboot while console / VGA were connected?

Comment: Multiple times for both. Are there any features in IPMI I could use to check the board's health? There are only few non critical events regarding fans but nothing else in the event log. Overheating is unlikely the cause. It's used mostly as NAS for backups.

Answer (score 0):

your yum update probably upgraded the Java version. I have had some IPMI consoles not working with Java 8 for example, but when I downgraded to Java 7, it worked.

Try downgrading your Java back to what it was before you updated and it should probably work.

Another thing would be that you might be expecting the Java plugin to work within the browser. This no longer works with Firefox, Chrome etc. You need to download the jnlp file and then manually use javaws to open that jnlp file.

See this post for some more info :

[How to run IPMI consoles now that NPAPI plugins are no longer supported?](https://serverfault.com/questions/867330/how-to-run-ipmi-consoles-now-that-npapi-plugins-are-no-longer-supported)